# This site uses a plugin (application/x-ieglue) that is unsupported

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Google chrome (Version 49.0.2623.108), so when I open my website/web-application it says "This site uses a plugin (application/x-ieglue) that is unsupported." on top of the webpage in the browser as shown in the image below. When I click on the the "learn more" link on it, It take me to [this page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033) but it doesn't have any info regarding "application/x-ieglue" or which part of my website is unsupported. I just want to understand why i'm getting this warning message when I'm opening the website. I'm seeing this warning message since a couple of months or may be before that.

[This is what I see on top of my website in the chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUqG4.png)

Comment: Do you use NPAPI plugins?

Comment: I'm not sure , how can can I find out if its used.

Comment: @takendarkk any suggestions?